# Can someone check my integration bounds? Joint PDF constant c

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Could someone could check my work in finding the constant c for joint pdf problems? I mainly want to verify my boundaries are correct.

a. $f_{XY}(x,y) = c \cdot y \cdot \log(x), \quad 2\leq x\leq y\leq3$
b. $f_{XY}(x,y) = c \cdot y \cdot e^{-x}, \quad 1\leq x \leq y \leq 2$
c. $f_{XY}(x,y) = c \cdot e^{-y}, \quad 0\leq x\leq1, x\leq y$
d. $f_{XY}(x,y) = c \cdot e^{-x-y}, \quad 0\leq y \leq x\leq 1$
e. $f_{XY}(x,y) = c \cdot e^{-x-y}, \quad  0\leq x \leq 1, x\leq y $

a.
$$\int_{2}^{3}\int_{2}^{y}c\cdot y\cdot\log(x)\,\,dxdy$$
b.
$$\int_{1}^{2}\int_{1}^{y}c\cdot y \cdot e^{-x}\,\,dxdy$$
c.
$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{1}^{x}c \cdot e^{-y}\,\,dydx$$
d.
$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{x}c \cdot e^{-x-y}\,\,dydx$$
e.
$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{x}^{1}c \cdot e^{-x-y}\,\,dydx$$
[Parts C and E](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTn30.png)

Comment: It can help just to make a picture on $X-Y$ plane.

Answer (score 0):

Part $c$ and part $e$ describe the same region and it is described differently, hence at least one of them must be wrong.

Note that $0< x<1$, $x < y < \infty$.

$$\int_0^1\int_{\color{red}x}^{\color{red}\infty} f_{x,y}(x,y)\, \,dydx$$

Comment: Fixed, does it look right now?

Comment: I have highlighted our differences. For such question, sketching out the corresponding region helps.

Comment: I've added a picture. If the integration bounds are from x to infinity, how would I integrate and get a numerical value? A numerical value is required to find c, the constant.

Comment: Are you able to compute $\int_0^\infty \exp(-x) \, dx$?

Comment: That is just 1, correct?

Comment: awesome, so working with integral where limit is $\infty$ is doable right?

Comment: Yes, but is my picture wrong? In my notes, the professor says something like:
$\int_{x1}^{x2}\int_{G_{Low}}^{G_{High}}f(x,y)dydx$ In this case, wouldn't GLow be x and GHigh be 1? And x1,x2 are obviously 0,1.

Comment: why should GHigh be $1$? why not $2$ or $3$, I don't see an upper bound being imposed in the domain description.

Comment: I sort of understand now. I may have copied something down incorrectly, as my professor has it from x to 1.